# How to use an OUT paramter / read data with SELECT from table in a MySQL procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, procedure

I am new in creating procedures in MySql and still learning it. So, I am stuck in creating procedures and need help. The question might seem basic but it will help me learn from basics.

**Question:**
I want to get the details of `salary` for each pilot when I specify his `pilot_nbr`.

#### Pilot Table consists of

- pilot_nbr (primary key)
- license_nbr
- last_name
- first_name
- title
- address
- phone
- office_nbr
- contract_type
- salary
- manager_nbr

#### Sample Data

```
'701', '7111', 'Dark', 'Jack', '1st officer', '6 street', '6042233445', '789', 'PTE', '145000.00', NULL 
'702', '7222', 'Mack', 'Bill', '1st officer', '7 street', '6043344556', '890', 'EMP', '155000.00', '701'
'703', '7333', 'Cheung', 'Charles', '2nd officer', '8street','6044455667','503','PTE','140000.00','701'  
'704', '7444', 'Gordon', 'Greg', '1st officer', '9 street', '6045566778', '123', 'EMP', '125000.00', '701'
'705', '7555', 'Basso', 'Nicki', '2nd officer', '5 street', '6046677889', '223', 'EMP', '163000.00', '701'
'706', '7666', 'Vettel', 'Sebast', '1st officer', '5 street', '6046677800', '523', 'EMP', '199000.00','701'
'707', '7777', 'Hawke','Mike','2ndofficer','7street','6046677326',423','EMP','139000.00','701'
```

Here is what I did and got stuck:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE pilot_Salary_Procedure( IN pilot_Number INT(20), OUT pilot_Salary DECIMAL(10,2))
 BEGIN 
 DECLARE pilot_NummberVariable INT(20);
 SELECT pilot_nbr INTO pilot_NumberVariable
 FROM pilot  
 WHERE pilot_nbr = pilot_Number;
 END //
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have done it that way (hoping that this is what you wanted):

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE pilot_Salary_Procedure( IN pilot_Number INT(20), OUT pilot_Salary DECIMAL(10,2))
 BEGIN 
 SELECT salary INTO pilot_Salary
 FROM pilot  
 WHERE pilot_nbr = pilot_Number;
 END //
```

You are then able to execute this procedure with

```
call pilot_Salary_Procedure(701, @salary);
```

The result then is stored in the session variable `salary`. You may read the value of this variable by issuing

```
select @salary;
```

and thus would get `145000` as result.

see also http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/call.html

NB: Be careful with your datatypes: Your notation above suggests that all your values in the table are string-like (for example CHAR or VARCHAR). Whilst this is perfectly okay for attributes like `first_name`, `last_name` or  `phone`, it hazardous for other's like `salary` or even discrete values like the identifiers (`pilot_nbr` or `manager_nbr`). Especially `salary` should be a `DECIMAL(15,2)` or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and yes it's working. I have a question that from where you wrote @ salary in call and select? There is no such thing in the create procedure. Why didn't you wrote @ pilot_Salary in CALL and SELECT because it's where output will be saved from salary column? This question will clear my confusion. Thanks a lot buddy

Comment: Don't mix up attribute/column name's of a table and session variables (think of them as if they were "local variables of your database connection"). I just used `salary` there out of "thin air" - I could have taken any other arbitrary name - even `my_grandma` and it would have worked (if used both in `call` and `select` consistently). This is how it works: `call` triggers the coding in the procedure, the result is stored in `pilot_salary`, which gets mapped to the session variable `salary` -- and with `call @salary` the value is just returned). Hope this helps.